# Spark version mismatch using maven dependencies

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I want ro run simple worcount ecample using apache Spark. Using local jar files in `$SPARK_HOME/jars` it runs correctly, but using maven dependancies it errors:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics.getThreadStatistics()Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsData;
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcJ$sp$1.apply(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcJ$sp$1.apply(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:149)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anonfun$1.apply$mcJ$sp(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.getFSBytesReadOnThreadCallback(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:203)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SparkTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("SparkTest");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/LICENSE");
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = rdd
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator())
                .mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1))
                .reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);

        counts.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("file:///home/XXX/Desktop/Processing/spark");

    }
}
```

Here is `POM.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Processing</groupId>
    <artifactId>Streaming</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-filesystem_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

It also included some othe apache software like Hadoop and Flink.

Spark version installed: `2.2.0`
Download link: `https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.2.0/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz`

Hadoop installde version = `2.7.3`

Something is mismatched here!

Comment: Post hadoop related dependencies from your pom too.

Comment: @philantrovert my code is note depending on Hadoop and according to official Spark site `In addition, if you wish to access an HDFS cluster, you need to add a dependency on hadoop-client for your version of HDFS.`

Comment: @philantrovert  Hadoop dependency is added however is not used.

Comment: Please provide all dependencies from your pom.xml, it seems to come from one of your dependencies

Comment: @PierreB. thanks, Updated.

Comment: Your class seems properly referenced with `hadoop-client` using the `hadoop-common` transitive dependency. What command did you run to package your app?

Comment: @PierreB. I use IntelliJ IDE. using local jars it runs successfully but using maven it errors!

Comment: @PierreB. When I check `spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar` in path `.m2/org/apache/spark/....` its not exactly the same as `spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar` in $SPARK_HOME/jars !

Comment: Using maven dependencies except `hadoop-client` and adding local spark `hadoop-common.jar` it works. But when I add `hadoop-common` to dependancies, It errora! Why? I dont know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your dependencies and showing how Java loads your class with `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.class.getResource("FileSyste‌​m.class")` it appears your jar is loaded from `org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2:jar:1.3.2`. When showing dependency tree with `mvn dependency:tree` we see its a transitive dependency from `flink-java:` and `flink-streaming-java_2.11`

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.flink:flink-java:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- ...
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.11:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.11:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2:jar:1.3.2:compile
```

This jar contains the entire `org.apache.hadoop.fs` package overriding the proper definition and causing your issue. You can try to remove the `flink-java` dependency or exclude `flink-shaded-hadoop2` *but that may cause issue with your code as other required Flink classes may be missing.* For example:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-shaded-hadoop2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-shaded-hadoop2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Otherwise you'll have to find another solution depending on your project requirements: play around with class loading to ensure your classes are loaded properly, update your dependencies versions so that the Hadoop classes match with Flink, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally creating another dedicated maven project for Spark with just `spark-core` maven dependency it works.

Can anyone say why?

Comment: Using your dependencies and showing how Java loads your class with `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.class.getResource("FileSystem.class")` it appears `org.apache.flink:flink-java:jar:1.3.2` define a transitive dependency `org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2:jar:1.3.2` which itself contains the entire `org.apache.hadoop.fs`package... Your app loads the class from this bogus jar instead of the proper one, hence your error. Using Spark Core as principal dependency seems like a proper work-around, but if you can exclude `flink-shaded-hadoop2` entirely without issues that will be better

Comment: @PierreB. Great! Post an answer and I will get it correct answer

Comment: Glad that'd help, I posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

As of Flink 1.4 (release pending), Flink can run without any hadoop dependencies, and if you need hadoop, having hadoop in the classpath is sufficient. This should make your life easier.